# Where to store public data and how to deploy it from GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I'm working on my project which is placed on AWS EC2 instance. I used CodeDeploy to deploy app from GitHub to EC2. But I want to store public data as stylesheets, JS, images etc on S3. It's even possible to deploy app on EC2 and S3 in one step? Or should I place all files to EC2 instance only?

I've been learning AWS documentation about Elastic Beanstal, CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, Ops Works and others for two days, but I confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have two steps in your deployment. One where you update your static assets in S3 and another where you update your servers and dynamic content on EC2 instances.

Here are some options:

1. Since they are static, just have every EC2 host upload the S3 assets to your bucket as a BeforeInstall script. You would need to include the static content as part of your bundle you use with CodeDeploy.
2. Use a leader election algorithm to do (1) from a single host. You could deploy something like Zookeeper as part of your CodeDeploy deployment.
3. Upload your static assets as a separately from your CodeDeploy deployment. You might want to look ad CodePipeline as a solution for a more complex multistage deployment (which can use CodeDeploy for your server deployment).

In either case, you will want to make sure that you aren't just overwriting your static assets or you'll end up in the situation where you old server code is trying to use new static assets. You should always be careful that you can run both versions of your code side by side during a deployment.

Comment: Bit late to the party, but this may be relevant wrt. not overwriting S3 resources: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27934256/1214598 - simply publish new assets to S3 under different version name folders

Answer (score 0):

I won't complicate it. I'll put all files to EC2 include CSS and JS by CodeDeploy from GitHub, because there is no simple and ideal solution for this.